# Antiforgery and cache-control header ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, cache-control, antiforgerytoken

I am trying to override `cache-control` header set by default antiforgery of asp.net core 2.0

.net core always sets it to `no-cache, no-store`. I am trying to use `private` which actually works as I wanted. `no-cache, no-store` doesn't seem to always work giving me some kind of `antiforgery token was meant for ... user..` kind of error occasionally. Which setting `cache-control` to `private` seems to solve.

But .net core doesn't let me override the default `cache-control` set by antiforgery.

I have tried following:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
  {
          HttpContext.Response.Headers.Append(Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.CacheControl, "private");
       ....
  }
```

Also

```
 public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
 {
       public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
       {
        // tried both
        //context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.CacheControl, "private");
        //context.HttpContext.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "private";
       }
 }
```

Note: using for http only right now

Answer (score 1):

Using antiforgery protection *requires* the `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store` header. The page with the token absolutely cannot be cached under any circumstances ever because the token is regenerated for each request of that resource and the right one has to be sent back in order to validate. In other words, it absolutely must be requested fresh from the server every single time. The `private` value is not good enough, as it still allows caching in certain scenarios.

The reason for your error is the user authentication status has changed, after the page was loaded and before the form is submitted. This could be caused by either user being logged in or logged out. The antiforgery token uses the authenticated user as part of itself, so if the user's authentication status changes, the token will no longer be valid after submitting. If the user logs in or logs out, you will need to ensure that the page is refreshed so that a new antiforgery cookie can be set.

Comment: I would like to think so, but as I am observing right now, on my login pages, its not so. On a different app made in .NET MVC i had success with `private` which previously was `no-cache, no-store`

Comment: "The page with the token absolutely cannot be cached [...] because the token is regenerated for each request of that resource and the right one has to be sent back in order to validate." I do not believe that old generated tokens are revoked/invalid as long as they are still for the same session. In my testing, I can grab a token value and use it in a later submit without issue. Put another way, I believe the tokens are session-based. If I'm correct, then why the seemingly-absolute necessity of `no-cache, no-store` over `private`?